# Scala Slick 3.1.1 inSetBind filter

Tags: playframework, slick

I'm trying to filter out results inside a slick 3.1.1 query in scala using a function like this:

```
  def filterByName(names: List[String]) = {
    val q = tableGames.filter(c => c.name inSetBind (names))
    println("FILTERBYNAME: " + q.result.statements.head)
    db.run(q.result)
  }
```

However, the results always end up empty. If I remove the filtering part it
correctly returns all elements in the database.
I've created a gist that runs an example end to end right here: [gist](https://gist.github.com/vicpara/f79b561307a56f1c05e1).

Is it a bug or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try following,

```
def filterByName(names: List[String]) = {
    val q = for { game <- tableGames if game.name inSetBind (names)} yield game
    println("FILTERBYNAME: " + q.result.statements.head)
    db.run(q.result)
  }
```